# Axios.get data from Mysql DB. Vue.js, Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

i created other Vue.js admin page for "writer" where i can dislpay data post from mysql DB posts. In admin page "admin" data responds and all is working.

Posts page wher i want data.

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h1>POOST</h1>

      <section class="posts-page">

        <div
            v-for="post in posts"
            :key="post.id"
            />
              {{ post }}
      </section>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: []
      }
    },
  
      created() {
        axios.get('/api/posts/').then(console.table())
    }
  
  }
</script>

<style>
```

API PostController.php

```
public function index()
    {
        return Post::with('user')->latest('id')->get();
    }
```

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Put a `@` symbol before curly bracket. Otherwise it will act as echo `@{{post}}`

Comment: @STA Error in console is
```Vue warn]: Property or method "post" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.```

Comment: and
```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 401

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the axios response to de post

```
async created(){  
const posts = await axios.get('/api/posts/');
this.posts = posts.data;
}
```